# Assistance Needed: Trouble Running Bare-Metal Code on second core in Cyclone V SoC

Tags: arm, intel-fpga, cyclone, multicore

I am working on intel cyclone 5 hps I have two cores in a processor Core 0 core 1, I want two code to run on two different cores core 0 and core 1 in bare metal.

When I run in jtag mode it works, for jtag i first debug using core 0 where i take core 1 out of reset it, than debug core 1 usign jtag it work

BUT, When i want to run both core usign qspi it only run core 0 not core 1

Here is the step i followed

**Firsly, loading preloader**
quartus_hps -c 1 -o P preloader-mkpimage.bin

**I make an image from bin file of core 0 and place it to qspi**

mkimage -A arm -O u-boot -T standalone -C none -a 0x00060000 -e 0 -n "baremetal image" -d core0.bin core0.img

quartus_hps -c 1 -o P -a 0x00060000 core0.img

**I make an image from bin file of core 1 and place it to qspi**
mkimage -A arm -O u-boot -T standalone -C none -a 0x00100000 -e 0 -n "baremetal image" -d core1.bin core1.img
quartus_hps -c 1 -o P -a 0x00100000 core1.bin

When i restart board only that code work which is in core 0, core 1 code not executing

I am setting **cpu1startaddress** 100000 apart from that in the code of core 0 also i am using alt_qspi function to to place bin file data in ddr,

I want to run in smp mode so I also set required aux_control_register **smp and fw** bit as stated in tech ref manual

alt_qspi_read((uint32_t *)BL_START/*ddr3 address*/, 0x100000/*qspi address*/, 0x40000);

In linker/scat file core 0 entry point is 0x60000 and

linker/scat file core 1 entry point is 0x100000

Comment: Have you got code in your Core 0 program to load the Core 1 program into memory and start execution? The preloader will only load the core0 program and launch that one. It is up to you to launch the second core.

Comment: Usually you would combine both programs into a single image file so that the preloaded will load both into RAM for you. If you are loading the second image manually, have you made sure to remove the 64byte header when copying it into DDR?

Comment: Also @TomCarpenter Can you please suggest how to combine both programs into a single image file or any command may be ??

Comment: For combining the image, if you have two bin files, you can use `objcopy --pad-to ...`  or [`dd`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196715/how-to-pad-a-file-to-a-desired-size) to ensure both binary files are the correct length (e.g first image is padded to 0x40000), and then `cat` to merge them into a single file. The merged result can then be fed into `mkimage`.

Comment: Great Thanks, @TomCarpenter I'll try.

Comment: If both are in the same image file, the preloader will do all the work for you, so you shouldn't have to do anything to load the Core 1 program, assuming they are both going to end up in consecutive locations in the DDR. If they are going in different locations things get more tricky..

Comment: @TomCarpenter i have found the issue, the problem is whenever second core come out of reset it goes to 0x0 address but I want it to be at 0x100000 I think I need to set vector table such that whenever second core come out of reset it goes to 0x100000 address but I am unable to find where to do these configuration, Do you have any idea, it will be great favor. 
Regards.

Comment: This has been cross-posted to Stack Overflow [Assistance Needed: Trouble Running Bare-Metal Code on second core in Cyclone V SoC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78078968) with probably no changes except losing the **bold** formatting.

Comment: No, @PeterCordes in stack over issue (in the end), I have specifically asked about issue of asking right configuration for how second core come out of reset so that it goes to 0x100000 address and I also mention there the link of this issue  as the query of stackover flow is the continuation of this post 
Regards